# PHP - SQL query foreach choice checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, foreach, while-loop

im trying made filter for multiple checkboxes values, but i have problem to get only specific data. I would like to tight results in a loop if I mark **choice[]** and **choice2[]**
I tried to add an additional value for each **foreach**, but I got an error *foreach () argument must be of type array | object, string given*

DATABASE

| id | ... | forWho | runeType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ... | tank | weapon |
| 2 | ... | mage | weapon |
| 3 | ... | archer | weapon |
| 4 | ... | tank | armor |
| 5 | ... | mage | armor |
| 6 | ... | archer | armor |

HTML

```
<div class="runesFilter-view">
    <div class="runesCheckBox">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice[]" id="check-tank" type="checkbox" value="tank" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check-tank">dla Tanka</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice1[]" id="" type="hidden" value="tank" />
    </div>
    <div class="runesCheckBox">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice[]" id="check-mage" type="checkbox" value="mage" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check-mage">dla Maga</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice1[]" id="" type="hidden" value="mage" />
    </div>
    <div class="runesCheckBox">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice[]" id="check-archer" type="checkbox" value="archer" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check-archer">dla Łucznika</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice1[]" id="" type="hidden" value="archer" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="runesFilter-view">
    <div class="runesCheckBox">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice[]" id="check-weapon" type="checkbox" value="weapon" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check-weapon">na Broń</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice2[]" id="" type="hidden" value="weapon" />
    </div>
    <div class="runesCheckBox">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice[]" id="check-armor" type="checkbox" value="armor" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check-armor">na Zbroję</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice2[]" id="" type="hidden" value="armor" />
    </div>
    <div class="runesCheckBox">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice[]" id="check-ring" type="checkbox" value="ring" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check-ring">na Pierścień</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice2[]" id="" type="hidden" value="ring" />
    </div>
    <div class="runesCheckBox">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice[]" id="check-amulet" type="checkbox" value="amulet" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check-amulet">na Amulet</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice2[]" id="" type="hidden" value="amulet" />
    </div>
    <div class="runesCheckBox">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice[]" id="check-artefakt" type="checkbox" value="artefakt" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check-artefakt">na Artefakt</label>
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice2[]" id="" type="hidden" value="artefakt" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['btSubmit']))
{
  if (!isset($_GET['choice']))
  {
    echo "<p class='align-center'><span class='badge bg-danger'>Wybierz najpierw typ run których szukasz</span></p>";
  }
  else 
  {
    $checked_array = $_GET['choice'];
    foreach ($_GET['choice1'] as $key => $value)
    {
      if(in_array($_GET['choice1'][$key], $checked_array))
      {
        $forWho = $_GET['choice1'][$key];

        $wybierz_ile = "SELECT * FROM runes WHERE forWho = ('$forWho')";
        $wez_ile = mysqli_query($polaczenie, $wybierz_ile);
        $pokaz_ile = mysqli_num_rows($wez_ile);

        if(empty($pokaz_ile))
        {
          echo "<p class='align-center'><span class='badge bg-danger'>Nie ma w bazie run <strong>$forWho</strong></span></p>";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "<p class='align-center'><span class='badge bg-success'>Znaleziono $pokaz_ile pasujących run dla klasy <strong>$forWho</strong></span></p>";
          while ($row_num = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wez_ile))
          {
              $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $row_num['runeName']);
              echo "<div class='runeWrapper'><div class='runeBoxImg $row_num[forWho]'><div class='runeImg'><img src='img/runes/rune-$string.png' alt='' /></div></div>",
              "<div class='runeBox'><p>Description 1</p></div>",
              "<div class='runeBox'><p>Description 2</p></div>",
              "<div class='runeBox'><p>Description 3</p></div></div>";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After click submit (before while) **var_dump($_GET['choice1'])**:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "tank"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "mage"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "archer"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "all"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "weapon"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "armor"
  [6]=>
  string(4) "ring"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "amulet"
  [8]=>
  string(8) "artefakt"
}
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Comment: Please, always show us ALL the error message not a summary. It is also useful to indicatae in the code which line is causing the error (as from the Line Number) in the error message as people often dont show us all the code

Comment: thx, im very begginer level in programming and any warning is very helpfull for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, before the loop add the following code and tell what the output was:

```php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_GET['choice']);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

I don't know why your HTML is structured this way but I think you could do the following:

```html
<div class="runesCheckBox">
        <input class="form-check-input" name="choice1[]" id="check-tank" type="checkbox" value="tank" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="check-tank">dla Tanka</label>
    </div>
```

```php
if (isset($_GET['btSubmit']))
{
  if (!isset($_GET['choice1']))
  {
    echo "<p class='align-center'><span class='badge bg-danger'>Wybierz najpierw typ run których szukasz</span></p>";
  }
  else 
  {
    foreach ($_GET['choice1'] as $forWho)
    {
        $wybierz_ile = "SELECT * FROM runes WHERE forWho = ('$forWho')";
        $wez_ile = mysqli_query($polaczenie, $wybierz_ile);
        $pokaz_ile = mysqli_num_rows($wez_ile);

        if(empty($pokaz_ile))
        {
          echo "<p class='align-center'><span class='badge bg-danger'>Nie ma w bazie run <strong>$forWho</strong></span></p>";
        }
        else
        {
          echo "<p class='align-center'><span class='badge bg-success'>Znaleziono $pokaz_ile pasujących run dla klasy <strong>$forWho</strong></span></p>";
          while ($row_num = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wez_ile))
          {
              $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $row_num['runeName']);
              echo "<div class='runeWrapper'><div class='runeBoxImg $row_num[forWho]'><div class='runeImg'><img src='img/runes/rune-$string.png' alt='' /></div></div>",
              "<div class='runeBox'><p>Description 1</p></div>",
              "<div class='runeBox'><p>Description 2</p></div>",
              "<div class='runeBox'><p>Description 3</p></div></div>";
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas, i was edit my first post with resoult of var_dump

Comment: I'm sorry. In `var_dump()` it should be `choice1` and not `choice`.

Comment: done, updated again in first post :) (i mark all 9 checkboxes, and push submit)

Comment: In this case, the entry is correct. Have you seen if the line of this foreach statement is the same as displayed in the error?